# rails7の「Turbo」と「link_to」と「jQuery」の相性悪くて困っています。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

**やりたいこと**
・ユーザーの退会処理を実装したい。(is_deleted)
環境:Rails 7.0.5, ruby 3.1.2p20, AWS EC2で管理。

**対象のソースコード**

```
<%= link_to "退会", users_hide_user_path(current_user), data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: '本当に退会しますか？' } %>
```

**コントローラ**

```
 def hide
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(is_deleted: true) #trueは退会してるかのことtrue=退会ずみ, false=退会済みでない
    reset_session
    flash[:notice] = "またのご利用心よりお待ちしております。"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

**ルーティング**

```
 resources :users do
    member do
      delete :hide, as: 'users_hide'
    end
 end
```

**エラーメッセージ**
・Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/users/1/hide"

色々調べた結果rails7から"method: :delete"の書き方が変わったので上記ソースコードのように記述すべきとのこと。
しかしTurboをオンにする必要がある。
しかしTurboをオンにすると次はjQueryのajax処理ができずビュー上でエラーになる。

app/javascript/application.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = $
window.$ = $

// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
// jQueryはturboと仲悪い
// import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
```

// import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"をコメントアウトすればjQeryは動くがmethod: :deleteが動かずにGETになってしまう。
コメントアウトを解除するとその逆になる。

参考URL:
[Turboがいろいろと厄介 | Rails 7.0 + Ruby 3.1でゼロからアプリを作ってみたときにハマったところあれこれ](https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/5c41a7031404c313da1f#turbo%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D%E3%81%A8%E5%8E%84%E4%BB%8B)

解決方法が知りたいです。